# Regex LookAhead limit to one (or first match)

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match the string (the answer) between numerous pre-set questions. The questions are jumbled, but they do start with "**Question:**" in front of each question. Followed in new line by "**Answer**".

```
regex = new Regex(@"(?s)(?<=What is blah blah..Answer)(.*)(?=Question)");
```

This regex gets me the answer correctly. But over-selecting all questions following.

Is there a way to limit the lookahead to the very first instance of "Question"?

Edit: 
Real sample question:

Question: What is potato made from?

Answer: *The predominantly from carbohydrate (starch)*  **<-only pick this part**

Question: What is tomato made from?

Answer: Not potatoes.

Comment: Show a real sample instead of writing "blahblah" in your regex, this will solve many assumptions. (input string, desired output, replacement or only match)

Comment: Thanks for the negative votes. It really helps me find an answer.

Comment: Do answers ever contain newlines?  If not, `@"Answer: (.*)"` should be all you need.

Comment: If you don't want the downvotes, make a better effort to write a good question instead of writing nonsense  like *blah blah*.

Comment: What difference is there between "blah blah" and an actual question? In the context of the question any text would work. I don't understand you delicate humans, getting upset over sample text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make the main part not-greedy by using

```
 .*? instead of .*
```

Comment: Thanks, glad someone actually wanted to help. :D